# Give parameters to grep command

Tags: linux, grep

I want to find some words from a file. I use grep command on linux.

grep "word1" original.file

But there are lots of words to find and they are in "words.file" If it is possible I want to give parameter to grep command. I will give words which are in the "words.file" to the grep command as parameters and find these words in the "original.file"

Can I do that ?

Comment: how the words in your words.file stored? one per line or with some character separated? If it is one word per line, thiton's solution should work. it would be nice if you put some sample data here.

Comment: Yes it is one word per line so thiton's solution has worked

Comment: then maybe you could choose thiton's solution as answer? I noticed that you 've asked 5 questions so far, and without a single accepted answer?

Comment: I answered "Was this post useful to you?" question to "Yes" I don't know what else I should do

Comment: "When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer." http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 5):

man grep helps you: grep has the -f parameter, which specifies that the patterns shall be read from a file.

```
grep -f words.file original.file
```

Mind, though, that the words in words.file must be one-per-line, but tr ' ' '\n' helps you with that.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
grep -e word1 -e word2 -e word3 original.file
```

If you want to build the `-e word`-things from `words.file` try

```
eval $(echo -n 'grep '; while read word; do echo -n "-e '$word' "; done < words.file; echo 'original.file')
```

Perhaps easier and better (but one grep process per word):

```
xargs -I '{}' grep -e '{}' original.file < words.file
```

Comment: While this is a nice introduction to shell-looping, you might want to know about grep -f :-)